# PHP file upload working for .txt but not for .pdf

Tags: php

Below Code is working fine for a .TXT file, but when I am selecting any .PDF file, it does not copies it to the destination path, Could someone please suggest me what should be the problem.

THE HTML code and PHP code as follows:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload.php" method="POST">

    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />

    Send this file: <input name="userfile" type="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>




<?php
$uploaddir = 'C:\xampp\htdocs\upload\\';

$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
echo $uploadfile;
echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:';
print_r($_FILES);

print "</pre>";

?>
```

Comment: What is the result of the debug informations you added?

Comment: Why the d ouble `\\`?

Comment: What's the size of the .pdf? Check (in php.ini or with `phpinfo()`) the allowed file size for uploads.

Comment: @putvande To prevent escaping the closing quote, of course.

Comment: `Possible file upload attack!`?? Why? It could be wrong permissions on the upload folder or other misconfiguration in the server.

Comment: the debugging information is as follows:                            Possible file upload attack!
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [userfile] => Array
        (
            [name] => BNKB_DOC111413.pdf
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 2
            [size] => 0
        )

)

Comment: @user3103991 Error 2 in `$_FILES` represents [`UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) => The uploaded file exceeds the `MAX_FILE_SIZE` directive that was specified in the HTML form.

Comment: @ProGM the debugging information is as follows: Possible file upload attack! Here is some more debugging info:Array ( [userfile] => Array ( [name] => BNKB_DOC111413.pdf [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 2 [size] => 0 ) )

Comment: Maybe you are using some additional security extension (suhosin?) that enforces additional checks. PHP by itself would allow anything to be uploaded that is below the maximum size in your PHP.ini. The error message you specified is definetly NOT from PHP or your script. There is some additional stuff involved.

Comment: @user3103991 Can you show us the HTML code used to submit the file?

Comment: @user555 Hi, Added the html code.. I have set the upload_max_filesixe to 40M

Answer (score 1):

Error number 2, given by the `$_FILES` array, represents [`UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE`](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php). From the PHP manual:

> The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was
>   specified in the HTML form.

In your HTML you have a hidden form field named `MAX_FILE_SIZE`. The field value represents the maximum file size of the uploaded file in bytes.

Either adjust the value of the field or remove it. I believe the field was a try from the PHP developers to implement client side browser check for the file size, stopping users from uploading too big files. However to date there is still no browser that enforces the value of that field.

Answer (score 0):

How big is your PDF file?

You may be reaching your web servers in-built MAX_FILE size (which I know you can change if using Apache).

Check your web server configuration.

Comment: I changed MAX_UPLOAD_FILESIZE to 40M and my pdf is of size 699 KB

Comment: @user3103991 So do you still have a problem or not?

Comment: Still its a problem to me.. although its not a showstopper to my project.. but i had to find it out why its not working for PDF.. i have set the max size in ini.. but not working..

Comment: After updating php.ini did you make sure to restart Apache? (Still assuming you are using Apache). Changes wont take effect until you give it a restart.

Comment: @user3103991 But it's not in the ini file. It's right there in the form, as explained by the error message, and you even posted it yourself! `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />`. That limits it to 30000 bytes, or ~29 kB. Remove that line, as @user555 said.

Comment: That's a max file size for your form, there is also a max file size as per your php ini file in the form of upload_max_filesize = 10M and
post_max_size = 10M